# Service Fabric - FileNotFoundException on Startup

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am unable to run any of the samples for ServiceFabric.

I'm using Windows 8.1, VS 2015 Community Edition (running as Adminstrator).
The ServiceFabric SDK is installed to the default location.

I receive a FileNotFoundException with the following stack trace:

```
at System.Fabric.Data.Log.Interop.NativeLog.IKPhysicalLogManager.EndOpenLogContainer(IFabricAsyncOperationContext Context, IKPhysicalLogContainer& Result)
at System.Fabric.Data.Log.Interop.PhysicalLogManager.OpenContainerEndWrapper(IFabricAsyncOperationContext Context)  
at System.Fabric.Data.Log.Interop.PhysicalLogManager.<OpenLogContainerAsync>b__5(IFabricAsyncOperationContext Context)
at System.Fabric.Interop.AsyncCallOutAdapter2`1.Finish(IFabricAsyncOperationContext context, Boolean expectedCompletedSynchronously)
```

Once I've hit this exception and I stop debugging, I can't even successfully deploy until I have selected the "Reset Local Cluster" option from the Service Fabric SDK system tray icon.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling, looking for hardcoded paths in the samples.

I'm able to run the samples on a different machine, but this is my primary development box. In both cases, I simply installed VS 2015 Community Edition, the SDK, and then attempted to run the samples. I moved the ServiceFabric paths to the beginning of my PATH variable, as suggested in the MSND forums, to avoid a conflict over a file named zip.dll as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem. Checked the suggestions here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-troubleshoot-common-scenarios.md

... regarding de FileNotFoundException, but everything is Copy Local. Can't seem to find what file is missing. I am running the very first sample of all: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-create-your-first-application-in-visual-studio/ .

In my case I am in Windows 10, running VS2015 Enterprise, and with Azure SDK 2.8.2 installed. I've rebooted more than once, as some posts suggest, to no avail. There is a thread here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-quick-start/ where this issue is also discussed, but no solutions are proposed.

**[Edit]**
Found the solution to the problem. Apparently Service Fabric requires 8Gb of free space on the disk. After freeing up space, the services seem to run fine. The hint was hidden in one of the many Event Log messages:

(The bold text means: "Not enough space on the disk").

AsyncCalloutAdapter-58892413: end delegate threw an exception
System.Fabric.FabricException: An error occurred during this operation.  Please check the trace logs for more details. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: **Não existe espaço suficiente no disco**. (Excepção de HRESULT: 0x80070070)
   em System.Fabric.Data.Log.Interop.NativeLog.IKPhysicalLogManager.EndCreateLogContainer(IFabricAsyncOperationContext Context, IKPhysicalLogContainer& Result)
   em System.Fabric.Data.Log.Interop.PhysicalLogManager.b__1(IFabricAsyncOperationContext Context)
   em System.Fabric.Interop.AsyncCallOutAdapter2`1.Finish(IFabricAsyncOperationContext context, Boolean expectedCompletedSynchronously)
   --- Fim do rastreio da pilha de excepção interna ---